# laravel validating array input with dependency and plugin laravel-jsvalidation

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have

- Laravel 5.5
- proengsoft's Laravel Javascript Validation (2.1.0) (A.K.A
  laravel-JsValidation)

The thing is, i have 2 inputs one says the type of contact that the user can enter (on a select input) e.g: *Phone - Job* and other where you can put that info e.g: *15623101601* (called "Contact"). These Inputs can be cloned with a button, so the user can enter as many contact data that (s)he wants, but it only validates the first input (One contact with it respectively contact type). What can i do to make the other fields generated on the client side can be validated as well?
The way that it be validated is that everytime that the user select something that it's not "Select a type of contact", the contact must be required.

This is my code:

On my blade:

```
... 
<!-- Contact field -->
    <div id="contact-field">
        <!-- Contact type field -->
        <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="contact_type_id" class="col-sm-3 form-control-label">
                    @lang('table.contact.type')
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    {{ Form::select('contact_type_id[]', $contact_types, $contact->contact_type_id, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('table.functionary.select_contact_type')]) }}
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="contact" class="col-sm-3 form-control-label">
                @lang('table.contact.title')
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                {{ Form::text('contact[]', $contact->content, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('table.contact.title')]) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
...
{!! JsValidator::formRequest('App\Http\Requests\UpdateProfileRequest', '#form'); !!}
(Javascript that creates more inputs)
function addContactField(){
    $('#contact-field').clone().appendTo('#append_contact');
    $('#append_contact').find("input[name='contact[]']").last().val("");
    $('#append_contact').find("input[name='contact_id[]']").last().val("null");
    $('#append_contact').find("option:selected").last().removeAttr("selected");
}
```

And Finally on the request:

```
...
return [
    'contact.'  => 'required_with:contact_type_id.'
];
...
```

I check [laravel's Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation), but it doesn't show anything related to dependency of arrays.
Thanks in advance and greetings!